# Remove items with certain keys from array

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$arr = [
    0 => "A",
    1 => "B",
    2 => "C",
    3 => "D",
    4 => "E",
];
```

And I want to delete few of the items, I have array of their keys:

```
$delKeys = [0,2,3];
```

The following procedure shows what I want to achieve:

```
foreach ($delKeys as $dk) {
    unset($arr[$dk]);
}
```

I'm left with:

```
array(
    [1] => "B",
    [4] => "E",
)
```

Is there a build in method that does the above 3-liner, like `array_filter`, but preserving the keys of the original array?

Comment: So what would be the expected output? If you want to preserve the keys?!

Comment: The above `foreach` works perfectly fine and I've shown the expected output with preserved keys. I'm wondering if there is build-in function that does the same. `array_filter` does it but it resets the keys (it generates new array with the non-filtered items).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two functions, but one line at least - [`array_diff_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) along with [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php):

```
array_diff_key($arr, array_flip($delKeys))
```

```
Array
(
    [1] => B
    [4] => E
)
```

Comment: Thanks, does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_diff_key($arr, array_flip($delKeys))
```

array_flip function will flip values in to keys and than array_diff_key find the difference between both the arrays

Comment: This is just a complete copy of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29279629/3933332

Comment: yes but provide explanation what actually happen using those functions

Comment: Well, I think it's pretty clear, but you can edit other's answers to add descriptions.

Answer (score -3):

You could always define your own function for this task:

```
/**
 * Remove the specified keys from a given array.
 *
 * @param  array $array
 * @param  array $keys
 * @return array
 */
function array_forget(array $array, array $keys)
{
    foreach ($keys as $key)
    {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Usage:

```
$arr = array_forget($arr, [0,2,3]);
```

Comment: Haven't you heard @PaulCrovella. Laravel is great and does all the things!

Comment: @PaulCrovella I meant the function was more based on the one Laravel defined for this task rather than, “Laravel defines functions, so therefore that’s the way to go!”

Comment: @PeeHaa See previous comment.